# Reading Error line from multiple files in python

Tags: python

I want read error line form multiple files using python. these files are in .log format.

I can read error when I hardcode the path of a particular file. Using below code

```
file_in = open('C:\\Users\\Rahul\\AppData\\Roaming\\JetBrains\\PyCharmCE2021.3\\test.log','r') # Read file
for line in file_in: # Loop every line
    if 'ERROR' in line: # Search for ERROR in line
        print(line) # Print line
    else: # Remove INFO and WARN lines
        pass # Print line
```

However I want to read it from multiple files at once. like I have 5 files and I want to read error line in each of these files. Below is code I am working .

```
import glob

file_list = glob.glob('C:\\Users\\Rahul\\AppData\\Roaming\\JetBrains\\PyCharmCE2021.3\\*.log')

my_list = []
path = "C:\\Users\\Rahul\\AppData\\Roaming\\JetBrains\\PyCharmCE2021.3\\*.log"
for file in glob.glob(path):
    print(file)
file_in=open('C:\\Users\\Rahul\\AppData\\Roaming\\JetBrains\\PyCharmCE2021.3\\outbrain_sample_failed.log','r') # Read file
for line in file_in: # Loop every line
    if 'ERROR' in line: # Search for ERROR in line
        print(line) # Print line
    else: # Remove INFO and WARN lines
        pass # Print line
```

However I am not able to read it. any suggestion or help ?

Comment: What is the current output of the program?

Answer (score 0):

Use nested for loops to check each file.

```
import glob

file_list = glob.glob('C:\\Users\\Rahul\\AppData\\Roaming\\JetBrains\\PyCharmCE2021.3\\*.log')  

for file in filelist:
    file_in = open(file, "r")
    for line in file_in.readlines(): # Loop every line
        if 'ERROR' in line: # Search for ERROR in line
            print(line) # Print line
        else: # Remove INFO and WARN lines
            pass # Print line
    file_in.close()
```